# Libgdx On Collision error

Tags: libgdx

I have tried to set up my own class for handling collisions but it just seems to output the error below. The program opens fine it only outputs the error when the ball and spike collide. Thanks

```
 Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alexcz.mariobros.Tiles.HandleCollisions.ballSpike(HandleCollisions.java:20)
    at com.alexcz.mariobros.Tools.WorldContactListener.beginContact(WorldContactListener.java:41)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.beginContact(World.java:982)
```

---

```
public class HandleCollisions {
    Character player;
    World world;

    public HandleCollisions(Character player, World world) {
        this.player = player;
        this.world = world;
    }

    public void ballSpike(){
        player.hitSpike();
        System.out.println("collided");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WorldContactListener implements ContactListener {
    public World world;
    public Character player;
    public HandleCollisions handleCollisions;

    public WorldContactListener(Character player,World world) {
        world = this.world;
        player = this.player;

        handleCollisions = new HandleCollisions(player, world);
    }

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

        if(fixtureA.getUserData() == "ball" || fixtureB.getUserData() == "ball"){
            Fixture ball = fixtureA.getUserData() == "head" ? fixtureA : fixtureB;
            Fixture object = ball == fixtureA ? fixtureB : fixtureA;

            if(object.getUserData() instanceof InteractiveTileObject)
            {
                ((InteractiveTileObject)object.getUserData()).hit();
                handleCollisions.ballSpike();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is telling you that handleCollisions is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your issue:

```
    world = this.world;    // this.world is null
    player = this.player;  // this.player is null
```

should be:

```
    this.world = world;
    this.player = player;
```

since `this` is your instance, that's how you would assign your class variables.

I'd guess that this is why your `handleCollisions` is `null`, and throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when it executes `handleCollisions.ballSpike()`.

Here's where a debug inspector comes in handy.